# IR Remote code not activating ON/OFF states

Tags: remote-control, code-review

The code below is for turning RGB lights on/off. The connections are as indicated in pin numbers. I found the resulting value of the buttons of the remote but when I used them in code it is not showing ON/OFF.

I assume there may be some practical errors. How to avoid such errors?

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 3;
int red = 13;
int blue = 12;
int green = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    long int getting = results.value;
    Serial.println(getting);
  }
  switch (results.value) {
    case 16582903:
      digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
      digitalWrite(green, LOW);
      break;
    case 16615543:
      digitalWrite(red, LOW);
      digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(green, LOW);
      break;
    case 16599223:
      digitalWrite(red, LOW);
      digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
      digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Enter ;");
  }
  irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `switch` to inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wiring is correct, the only mistake I could see is that your variable named "getting" used in switch is inside the if, and it should be at least in the same level of switch. Also, your resume needs to be inside the if.

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 3;
int green = 11;
int blue = 12;
int red = 13;

#define code1  16582903 // Must match exactly the code generated by the IR button, would be something like 0xFF906F
#define code2  16615543
#define code3  16599223

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    //this checks to see if a code has been received
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    unsigned int getting = results.value;
    Serial.println(getting);
    switch (getting) {
      case code1:
        digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
        digitalWrite(green, LOW);
        break;
      case code2:
        digitalWrite(red, LOW);
        digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(green, LOW);
        break;
      case code3:
        digitalWrite(red, LOW);
        digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
        digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
        break;
      default:
        Serial.println("Enter ;");
    }
    irrecv.resume(); //receive the next value
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the delay(100); I was combining IR remote, with HC-SR04 with adafuit sound board. I was getting random input when IR remote was used. Adding the delay solved (after 3 days). Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: @Andres nice! Well Done.

Answer (score 1):

I would change "unsigned int getting = results.value;" to "unsigned long getting = results.value;" in Andrew's sketch and use it. I don't know what "type" of Arduino you are using, but I know on the Uno and other ATMEGA based boards, unsigned ints yield a useful range of 0 to 65,535. Unsigned long will give you a range from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

If you press ANY button and hold it down for a while on some IR remotes, code 4294967295 will be sent. This is true for the "Car" remotes: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00SMI1GZA/ref=pe_386430_126088100_TE_item, Apple TV (2nd generation) remote, and LG 50" TV remote.

One minor issue I found with both sketches is I could not get them to compile. I had to remove the space between "#" and "include" and the spaces between "<" and ">" in "# include < IRremote.h >". I am using an older version of the IDE which may explain it. Arduino UNO. IDE Version 1.0.6.2, GCC 4.2.1 on OSX 10.6.8.